# Is there a way to move navigation zone and main zone to the center of the page in SharePoint 2013 search result page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, enterprise-search, branding

I have a custom branded SharePoint 2013 enterprise search page, when a search query is executed the result is populated on the left side if the page.
[image]

As you can see everything is on the left side, i want to move it to the centre of the page, I couldn't even figure out which bit to edit in the designer as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to center the content section of the page, I would use css to re-style the #contentBox as follows:

```
#contentBox {
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto; 
width:1200px; // this should be set to whatever you want to fix the width of the page at
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are just SharePoint pages based on a page layout. If you have already created a new master page you can create your own page layout and add the web parts wherever you like.